# How to detect whether JTextField is blank?

Tags: java, sockets, jframe, client, chat

I have made a chat client application and I am stuck on the login dialog. Basically, I want the register button event to detect whether the user entered anything into the field box. This code isn't working.

```html
public class RegButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
 {
  if(userBox.getText() != null)
  {
   System.out.println("Lol");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking for the empty string instead?

Comment: I've tried checking if it equals null (== instead of !=), but nothing happens at all. It's as if the JTextField userBox is never null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's empty (in this case, not empty) in two ways:
using `isEmpty(`) or `equals("")`

```
if (!userBox.getText().isEmpty()){
    //code
}
```

or

```
if (!userBox.getText().equals("")){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the difference when using == or .equals? == for integers?

Comment: @DeanHampson `==` checks for *referential equality*, that is "do these two references point at exactly the same object?". `.equals` checks for logical equality, i.e. "do these two objects represent the same thing?". `==` for Integers is a special case, and it's simpler if you just stick to using `.equals` for them.

Answer (score 2):

TRy this code

```
public class RegButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource == userBox) {
           if(!userBox.getText().isEmpty())
           {
            System.out.println("Lol");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```js
if(!userBox.getText().equals(""))
{
     System.out.println("ABC");
}
```